# How to make right and bottom css properties work on a textarea in IE? (IE9 and below)

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Setting my textarea's css style bottom: 5px; will not work as expected, means will not change it's height.. like would do in chrome.

Comment: I'm confused about what you are trying to do. "right" and "bottom" are positioning styles, not sizing styles. Please post your code.

Comment: You should show your html. This question, as it is, is unanswerable.

Comment: the situation is like in this jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/44pwh/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're talking about something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/44pwh/

```
<div style="position:relative; width:360px; height:180px">
    <textarea style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0"></textarea>
</div>
```

..there's no way to make it work in IE9.

In fact, it only works in WebKit browsers.

It's probably something to do with `textarea` being a [replaced element](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements), and WebKit handling it differently to other layout engines.

---

As a workaround, you can apply `top`/`right`/`bottom`/`left` to a wrapper `div`, then add the `textarea` inside that `div`. Then, add this:

```
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/44pwh/1/

`box-sizing: border-box` is to make the `textarea` fit perfectly - without it, the default `padding`/`border` would make the `textarea` slightly larger than ideal.

Comment: So, how could I set the sizes of a textarea to be crossbrowser? I would liked to set the left and right instead of direct width/height..

Comment: You simply can't size a `textarea` in this way, except in WebKit. Why do you need to be able to do it like this? Everybody else manages to do it using `width` and `height` :) If it's just for one particular layout (not something abstract), a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you have so far will help.

Comment: Im building a framework that and everything is absolutely positioned. Now I need to have a textarea that is always top:right:bottom:left:10px relative to the parent element (this is one case). In order to to that I have to always calculate the width/height of all elements.. only because of IE..

Comment: You can apply `top`/`right`/`bottom`/`left` to a `div`, then add the `textarea` in that `div`. Add `width:100%; height:100%; box-sizing:border-box` to the `textarea`. That's all you can do.

Comment: perfect! I didn't think about that.. change your answer to accept it ;) thanks!