# Absolute positioning <input> with "left" and "right" in IE9 doesn't work

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, css-position

I use a CSS trick where I set `position: absolute` on an element, and then set like `left: 0px; right: 70px` to make sure that the element spans the whole length of the parent, but always leaving 70px space to the right.

However, I recently found that this trick does not work in IE9 for **text input** elements. The "left" and "right" properties does not alter the default width of the element at all. Does any one know a workaround for IE9?

Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sqa7x/), although you have to be viewing it in IE9 to see the effect...

Comment: That's weird, it should do. Are you sure you have a `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the start of your document? Otherwise you're in Quirks Mode, which doesn't like absolute positioning at all.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol thanks for comment, yes I have the doctype tag. I am using that on an input element, I think that might be the problem somehow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430103/how-to-make-right-and-bottom-css-properties-work-on-a-textarea-in-ie-ie9-and-b/7430496#7430496. That answer talks about `textarea` instead, but it's otherwise the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input elements don't like being stretched like that. Put it in a containing `<div>`, position the `<div>`, and then use `width:100%` on the input.

Comment: Yes I came across this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708654/using-positionabsolute-to-set-an-inputs-width and found the solution. To be honest I don't really like that approach as I have to add additional wrapper but it seems that's the only path I can take to support IE9.